# Adaptive formula in google sheets by apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get a formula added in a spreadsheet (Google sheets) which basically generates the email address of a person based on his first and last name (what the email addresses look like in my company). The full code is basically a method to go from a form I made in sheets, to a line (row) in another tab in the same spreadsheet. Here is the full code, I'm having problems with the last line.

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
const dataWS = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
const formWS = ss.getSheetByName("Form")
const settingsWS = ss.getSheetByName("Settings")

const lr = dataWS.getRange(dataWS.getMaxRows(),5).getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow()

const idCell = formWS.getRange("D3")
const checkbokx = formWS.getRange("D5").getValue()
const emptyCell = formWS.getRange("J6").getValue()

const fieldRange =["D7","D9","H9","J6","H7","J7","D11","H11","D13","H13","D15","H15","D17","D19","H17","J8","H19","D21","H21","D23","J9","J10","J11","H23","D25"]

function saveRecord() {

const fieldValues = fieldRange.map(f => formWS.getRange(f).getValue())

const nextIDCell = settingsWS.getRange("A2")
const nextID = nextIDCell.getValue()
fieldValues.unshift(checkbokx,emptyCell,nextID)

//console.log(fieldValues)

dataWS.appendRow(fieldValues)
idCell.setValue(nextID)
nextIDCell.setValue(nextID+1)

//Add a checkbox when appending a new row
var checkbox = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build()
dataWS.getRange(lr+1,1).setDataValidation(checkbox).setValue(checkbokx)

dataWS.getRange(lr+1,7).setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK(E2),"",CONCATENATE(E2,".",F2,"@mycompany.com"))')

}
```

The entire code works, but the last line is giving me some problems. So the formula should give me the first name (E-column in sheets), a dot and the last name (F-column in sheets), followed by @mycompany.com. This happens, but the formula does not adjust to the next lines in sheets, so it always goes to the name in E2 and F2, even on later rows which have different names in the E and F column.

The program should only add this formula in the final row (the one being added by filling in the form), the previous ones should already have been done.

I have tried to get the current row by adjusting the formula with dataWS.getRange("E2").getValue() for the E2 and F2 parts, but this doesn't seem to work. I think this is because I'm working between '', but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `setValue()` as an untested alternative?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I think the big issue I was having is the mixing in apps script language in the formula for Google Sheets. The answer by Tanaike below solved my problem, but thanks for helping me as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `I'm having problems with the last line.` and `The program should only add this formula in the final row (the one being added by filling in the form), the previous ones should already have been done.`, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use the values of columns "E" and "F" of the row of `lr + 1` with your formula of `=IF(ISBLANK(E2),"",CONCATENATE(E2,".",F2,"@mycompany.com"))`.

In this case, how about modifying your script as follows?

#### From:

```
dataWS.getRange(lr+1,7).setFormula('=IF(ISBLANK(E2),"",CONCATENATE(E2,".",F2,"@mycompany.com"))')
```

#### To:

```
dataWS.getRange(lr + 1, 7).setFormulaR1C1('=IF(ISBLANK(R[0]C[-2]),"",CONCATENATE(R[0]C[-2],".",R[0]C[-1],"@mycompany.com"))');
```

- By this modification, the values of columns "E" and "F" of the row of `lr + 1` are used.

#### Reference:

- [setFormulaR1C1(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformular1c1formula)